# MariaDB trigger, autoupdate field on edit?

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb, edit

I have a DB based on Maria DB and a table "values" with two fields (for example): "X" and "Y".
I want to create a trigger that, on insert and on update of X, makes Y = X / 10.

I've tried something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_trig AFTER UPDATE OF X ON values
BEGIN
     update values SET values.Y = X/10 WHERE X = NEW.X;
END;
```

But obviously it is not working. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had numerous problems.  This should be closer

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_trig BEFORE UPDATE ON `values`
FOR EACH ROW
     SET NEW.Y = NEW.X/10;
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_trig BEFORE INSERT ON `values`
FOR EACH ROW
     SET NEW.Y = NEW.X/10;
```

Unclear:  If `X` did not change, do you still want `Y` to be set to `X/10`?

Note `BEFORE`, `NEW` and `OLD`, using `SET`, not `UPDATE`, 2 triggers, etc.

Comment: Thanks, it works but there is a problem. Y value becomes X/10 only on Y update, and not on X update like i want. How i can solve it?

Comment: I recommend you _not_ use `TRIGGERS` or Stored Routine in your _first_ work in SQL.  You have a lot to learn without stumbling over these issues.  Please provide the equivalent SQL _without_ Triggers; then maybe I can understand what you mean about X, not Y.

Comment: This will not work!! In before insert OLD doesn't exist!

Comment: I sense conflicting requirements.